# Port tunnelling from behind firewall to remote server via VNC'd laptop?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, firewall

I have a command-line application on linux that uses a specific port to talk to a remote server. Unfortunately, at work, that port is blocked.

I am able to connect my laptop via VNC to the network, and the laptop is on a wifi connection that *does* have port access to the remote server. I am able to ssh to my laptop from the secure network when it is connected.

Is there a way of using ssh port tunnelling to work around this? Can I port tunnel to my laptop and have my laptop act as a middle-man between the firewalled network and the remote server?

Many thanks.

Comment: This might get way more help in [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) SE sites.

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correct you can call ssh from where you are to reach your laptop. Then you should be able to do something like this:

```
ssh -f -N -L <local port>:<remote server ip or hostname>:<remote server port> <laptop ip or hostname>
```

This will create start a tcp listening port on the host where ssh originates that forwards to your remote host and port via the machine you ssh to.

Excerpts from https://man.openbsd.org/ssh

```
-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
-L [bind_address:]port:remote_socket
-L local_socket:host:hostport
-L local_socket:remote_socket
Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket on the local
(client) host are to be forwarded to the given host and port, or Unix
socket, on the remote side. This works by allocating a socket to listen to
either a TCP port on the local side, optionally bound to the specified
bind_address, or to a Unix socket. Whenever a connection is made to the
local port or socket, the connection is forwarded over the secure channel,
and a connection is made to either host port hostport, or the Unix socket
remote_socket, from the remote machine.
Port forwardings can also be specified in the configuration file. Only the
superuser can forward privileged ports. IPv6 addresses can be specified by
enclosing the address in square brackets.
By default, the local port is bound in accordance with the GatewayPorts
setting. However, an explicit bind_address may be used to bind the
connection to a specific address. The bind_address of “localhost” indicates
that the listening port be bound for local use only, while an empty address
or ‘*’ indicates that the port should be available from all interfaces.

-f
Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution. This is
useful if ssh is going to ask for passwords or passphrases, but the user
wants it in the background. This implies -n. The recommended way to start
X11 programs at a remote site is with something like ssh -f host xterm.
If the ExitOnForwardFailure configuration option is set to “yes”, then a
client started with -f will wait for all remote port forwards to be
successfully established before placing itself in the background.

-N
Do not execute a remote command. This is useful for just forwarding ports.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried this out, but without success so far. One issue straight away was that it doesn't even make a connection when it uses ipv6 (by default), so a -4 option is necessary.

Comment: Does ssh open the local listening port but it doesn't reach out or does cannot you connect to the port on 127.0.0.1 at all?

Comment: Hi @nissefors. Thanks for your comment, I've just realised that I misunderstood what the ssh command is doing. It opens up a port that can be accessed at localhost. The problem is that (AFAIK) I can't tell the command-line application to use localhost instead of the server. So the port tunnelling works, I just can't tell the command-line tool about it.

Comment: So you have a command line tool that you cannot instruct to go anywhere else than <remote server>. Is it tied to it by ip or by hostname? if it is by hostname you cold make an entry in your local hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks @nissefors, yes, that should work.